# Calculate complex integral with double exponential using path integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}} \,dt$$

I'm trying to calculate the above integral. I've been told as a hint to see it as an integral along a path, so I've tried to think of it as the integral along a circle with centre 0, radius 1. Since it is a closed path, then the integral would be 0?

I'm self teaching complex analysis and it is new to me, so is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: Compute the integral $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{e^z}{z} dz.$

Comment: @Fred Thanks for your help - I've just plugged it in and it gives the same integral as the one in the question. The way that I know how to do path integrals is by converting it to a standard integral, I'm not sure how to do it the other way, please can you help?

Comment: $$e^{e^{it}}=1+e^{it}+\frac{e^{2it}}{2!}+ \,...\,;\qquad \int_0^{2\pi}e^{ikt}dt=0\,\,\text{at}\,\,k=1, 2, 3, ...$$

Comment: Your argument for a value of $0$ is wrong. The integral is only over a closed path after you substitute e.g. $z=e^{it}$, converting an interval into a circle, but then the new integrand is only meromorphic, not analytic.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Very nice approach ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but be careful how you make the substitution.  As $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, $e^{it}$ will go around the unit circle, so you want to substitute $z=e^{it}$.  However, you also get $dz=ie^{it}\,dt=iz\,dt$ so $dt$ becomes $\frac{dz}{iz}$ and the whole integral becomes $$\int_C \frac{e^z}{iz}\,dz$$ where $C$ is the unit circle.  Because of the $z$ in the denominator, this integrand has a pole at $z=0$ and is not holomorphic on the unit disk, so you cannot conclude that the integral is $0$.  Instead, by the Cauchy integral formula, $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{e^z}{z}\,dz$$ is just the value of the function $e^z$ at $0$, which is $1$.  Comparing this to your integral, you get that your integral is $2\pi$.